# apache ssl cert issues

Tags: apache-2.2, sendmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hosting 2 different SSL domains on the same IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/244419/hosting-2-different-ssl-domains-on-the-same-ip)

I have 2 domains with two different certificates from the same CA. I'm using CentOS and am wondering how to set this up for 2 certificates. In my ssl.conf file, I have:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain1.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/domain1.com.key
```

In my http.conf file, I'm overriding these values for the second domain:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain2.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/domain2.com.key
```

What I get when I try and connect is that the domain does not match the certificate. How can I do this so as to use both domains? If I was using just 1 domain, there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Is this a sendmail, or apache issue? You say sendmail in the subject, but state http.conf in the body.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming Apache since those are Apache configuration options.  You're probably hitting the common mistake of trying to run two domains on the same port and IP.  Since SSL happens before the HTTP request is sent, each domain requires a different port and/or different IP address.